# Wildfly tries to open wrong server

Tags: wildfly

While accesing a remote database Wildfly is not able to connect to it, it tries to access COMPNAME (my computer's name) as if it was the selected database instead of the one defined on datasource, that of course doesn't exist.

I have used the same conection properties on datasource to access database with SQL Server Management Studio and it works perfectly, the standalone configuration is the same as in my old computer where it worked.

This is the datasource:

```
  <datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:/SQLDESTINATION" pool-name="SQLDESTINATION" enabled="true" use-ccm="true">
    <connection-url>jdbc:sqlserver://urlthatworks:1433;DatabaseName=DB_NAME</connection-url>
    <driver-class>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</driver-class>
    <driver>sqljdbc4.jar</driver>
    <security>
        <user-name>userok</user-name>
        <password>passok</password>
    </security>
    <validation>
        <valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mssql.MSSQLValidConnectionChecker"/>
        <background-validation>true</background-validation>
    </validation>
</datasource>
```

And here is wildfly log:

```
2019-09-27 13:29:53,126 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 71) javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000453: Unable to get managed connection for java:/SQLDESTINATION
2019-09-27 13:30:07,483 WARN  [org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 71) IJ000604: Throwable while attempting to get a new connection: null: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ031084: Unable to create connection
.......
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Cannot open server "COMPNAME" requested by the login.  The login failed.
```

So problem is that instead of trying to get to "DB_NAME" it is trying to access "COMPNAME"
Difference that I guess shouldn't matter is old computer was using windows 7 and this one windows 10 and in old computer wildfly folder was under C:\Users\myusername\wildfly-10.1.0.Final folder  while in new one it is in D:\wildfly-10.1.0.Final

Comment: Can you try with the following connection url? `<connection-url>jdbc:sqlserver://urlthatworks:1433/DB_NAME</connection-url>`

Comment: It doesn't like it
`Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Port number 1433/DB_NAME is not valid.`

Comment: Leave wildfly aside, are you able to connect to the db server via a command line or GUI client?

Comment: Yes, I'm able to connect db server and use it without problems

Comment: Did you try using connection properties instead ? http://wildscribe.github.io/WildFly/17.0/subsystem/datasources/data-source/ExampleDS/connection-properties/index.html https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/sql/connect/jdbc/setting-the-connection-properties?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Is it possibly case sensitive and expecting `databaseName`?

Comment: It isn't case sensitive sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it work by changing the folder to C:\Users\myusername\wildfly-10.1.0.Final although this doesn't explain why on D: it would try to overwrite the server name with my computer name.

Answer (score 0):

Try `databaseName=DB_NAME` instead of `DatabaseName=DB_NAME`.

Comment: I'm afraid it keeps with same error, it seems not to be case sensitive